# Display the top two most popular activities across all reservations

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

The Table is

`SUPERVISION (ResNo, ActivityID, SupervisorID, Day, Time)`

I have done something like this but it is wrong

```
SELECT COUNT(S.Res, S.ActivityID) AS PopularActivities
FROM Supervision S
WHERE rownum = 2;
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

or

```
SELECT S.ResNo, S.ActivityID
FROM Supervision S
WHERE (rank() over (order by count(*) DESC) as RNK
    from Supervision S) AND rnk = 2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put it in a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        ActivityID, COUNT(*) AS Cnt
    FROM Supervision
    GROUP BY ActivityID
    ORDER BY Cnt DESC
) t
WHERE rownum <= 2
```

Alternatively, you can use `RANK` to achieve the same result:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        ActivityID, 
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ActivityID ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS rnk
    FROM Supervision
    GROUP BY ActivityID
) t
WHERE rnk <= 2
```

Comment: Thanks I got the answer of what I needed, and how will I show the result as having the activity name?

Table is

ACTIVITY (ActivityID, ActName, ActDescription, ActRate, RiskLevel)

Comment: Do a `JOIN` after the subquery.

Comment: how? I am not very familiar with these

Comment: SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        ActivityID, COUNT(*) AS Cnt JOIN ..........?
    FROM Supervision
    GROUP BY ActivityID
    ORDER BY Cnt DESC
) t
WHERE rownum <= 2

Comment: `SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        ActivityID, COUNT(*) AS Cnt
    FROM Supervision
    GROUP BY ActivityID
    ORDER BY Cnt DESC
) t
INNER JOIN Activity a
 ON a.ActivityID = t.ActivityID
WHERE rownum <= 2`

Answer (score 0):

For me, what I did is this:

```
ORDER BY TIME DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        ActivityID, COUNT(*) AS top
    FROM Supervision
    GROUP BY ActivityID
    ORDER BY top DESC
) t
limit 0,2
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the two most popular activities across all reservations.

This means that you want to count the reservations of each activity type, and take the two with the highest count.

Another way to say it is, you want to group the reservations by activity, count them, order the result decrescently, and take the first two

It looks like you are using Microsoft TSQL syntax, so it should look like this:

```
SELECT TOP 2 ActivityID, COUNT(*)
  FROM SUPERVISION
  GROUP BY ActivityID
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```